# Ubuntu display messed up after update to 16.04

Tags: 16.04, display

After recently upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04, the display has become messed up. I can't see the launcher, so I can't see any apps. I can't right-click either, so no copying or pasting. I also can't see an exit or minimise button on applications which I do manage to open miraculously. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If you can open terminal so send result of this command:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If you can not open terminal press `Ctrl + Alt + F1` to open it.If it does not work you must open terminal from `Advanced options` in `grub2` menu(when you restart you computer).
don't forget you must be connected to Internet.